# ORA-02158: invalid CREATE INDEX option trying to create an index cluster

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I am trying to create an index cluster in Oracle SQL, but when I try to create the index for it, I get the following error:

```
ORA-02158: invalid CREATE INDEX option
02158. 00000 -  "invalid CREATE INDEX option"
*Cause:    An option other than COMPRESS, NOCOMPRESS, PCTFREE, INITRANS,
           MAXTRANS, STORAGE, TABLESPACE, PARALLEL, NOPARALLEL, RECOVERABLE,
           UNRECOVERABLE, LOGGING, NOLOGGING, LOCAL, or GLOBAL was specified.
*Action:   Choose one of the valid CREATE INDEX options.
```

And this is the code I'm trying to execute

```
CREATE CLUSTER index_cluster_t1_col1 (col1 INTEGER) INDEX;
CREATE INDEX index_cluster_index ON CLUSTER index_cluster_t1_col1(col1);
```

The first line works fine, but the error comes up when I try to execute the second one. I've been following the [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-INDEX.html#GUID-1F89BBC0-825F-4215-AF71-7588E31D8BFE__I2182500) and not sure what part of the syntax I'm missing. The index options parameters seem to be optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE INDEX index_cluster_index ON CLUSTER index_cluster_t1_col1;
```

You've already defined which columns are in the cluster; you don't need to repeat that information in the `create index` command. Just name the cluster.